# Angular 2 Display Multiple Layer Entities for JSON with Pipe and filtering

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have this json :

```
  {
"id": 1,
"player_id": 265,
"player_name": "MS Dhoni",
"player_role": "WK",
"player_type": "C",
"player_price": 1000000,
"player_points": null,
"franchise": {
  "id": 1,
  "franchise_id": 58,
  "franchise_name": "CSK"
}
```

}

I have created Two POJO Classes in angular:

Team.ts

```
export class Team {

player_name: String;

player_role: String; }
```

Franchise.ts

```
export class Franchises {

franchise_name: String;}
```

Getting the JSON Data in service class from:

```
getPeople(): Observable<any> {
    /*return this.http.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map(res => res.json());*/

        return this.http.get('PATH')
          // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
          .map((res:Response) => res.json())
          //...errors if any
          .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Initializing in the component:

```
this.data = team_selectionService.getPeople();
```

**Now I just need player_name, player_role, player_price, and franchise_name. I am getting All of it but only able to filter using Player name and Player Role. Franchise_name filter is not working properly. I have added the filter code at the bottom as well.**

How do I initialize the entity classes correctly (Team.ts, and Franchise.ts) to get the franchise data properly?

Below is the html i am using:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="filter.player_name" placeholder="Name"></th>
          <th><input type="text" name="role" [(ngModel)]="filter.player_role" placeholder="Role"></th>
          <th><input type="text" name="team" [(ngModel)]="filter.franchise_name" placeholder="Team"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

<tr>
  <td colspan="4">
    <label for="limit">Limit: </label><input type="number" name="limit" [(ngModel)]="limit" min="1" [attr.max]="[numberOfPlayers]" step="1" placeholder="Limit">
    <label for="page">Page: </label><input type="number" name="page" [(ngModel)]="page" min="1" [attr.max]="[numberOfPlayers]" step="1" placeholder="Page">
  </td>
</tr>

<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let team of teams | teamfilter:filter">
            <td>{{team.player_name}}</td>
            <td>{{team.player_role}}</td>
            <td>{{team.franchise.franchise_name}}
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Below is the code for pipe my-filter.ts:

```
transform(items: Team[], filter: Team): Team[] {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    // filter items array, items which match and return true will be kept, false will be filtered out
    return items.filter((item: Team) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  }

applyFilter(team: Team, filter: Team): boolean {
    for (let field in filter) {
      if (filter[field]) {
        if (typeof filter[field] === 'string') {
          if (team[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[field].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (typeof filter[field] === 'number') {
          if (team[field] !== filter[field]) {
            return false;
          }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I think I am missing something in the pipe filter. I need to add it to filter the Franchise to a third level, but I am not really sure about it.

Please throw in any ideas you have.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `String` object for determining property type. Instead, use the `string` primitive.

And if you need positioning your html elements, it's not a good practice to use tables. You should go with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or good ol' [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Also, where are you subscribing to the Observable? Can you show us your component.ts?

Comment: your function getPeople() return a Observable, so you NOT WANT make this.data=myObservable. You WANT myObservable.subscribe(res=>this.data=res)

Comment: this.team_selectionService.getPeople().subscribe(
            (teams: Team[]) => {
              this.teams = teams;
              this.numberOfPlayers = this.teams.length;
              this.limit = this.teams.length; // Start off by showing all books on a single page.

            });

Comment: I am subscribing the observable in ngOnInit as the above comment

Comment: I think I need to include the Franchise entity in the pipe filter code, but I am not sure how to do to given that Franchise is a child entity of Team.